# Nodejs 'fs' methods running asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs, read-write

Using the `fs` package in Node.js, I am getting some unexpected results I am hoping to have some light shed on here.

I have the following code:

```
client.on('fileChannel', function(data){
        console.log(data);

        fs.writeFile('/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC', "", (err) => {
            if (err) {console.log(err)};
            console.log('UDC Halted');
        });

        fs.readFile('/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {console.log(err)};
            console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
        });


        // Attach file to libcomposite
        if (data.Command === "Attach") {

            numAttachedFiles = Object.keys(fileTracker).length;

            lunNum = 'lun.'+numAttachedFiles;
                fileTracker[lunNum] = data.Argument;
                editFile = '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/functions/mass_storage.usb/'+lunNum+'/file';
                fs.writeFile(editFile, __dirname+'/uploads/'+data.Argument, (err) => {
                    if (err) {console.log(err)};
                    console.log('File Attached');
                });
        }

        // Reconnect UDC
        fs.readdir('/sys/class/udc', function(err, dirContents) {
            console.log(dirContents);
                if (err) {console.log(err)};

                fs.writeFile('/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC', dirContents[0], (err) => {
                    if (err) {console.log(err)};
                    console.log('UDC Reconnected');
                });
        });

    });
```

which results in (invoking input after `//`):

```
{ Command: 'Attach', Argument: 'jsmpeg-master.zip' } // console.log(data);
[ 'fe980000.usb' ] // console.log(dirContents);
UDC Halted // console.log('UDC Halted');
File Attached // console.log('File Attached');
[Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, write] {
  errno: -16,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'write'
} // fs.writeFile('/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC'...if (err) {console.log(err)};
UDC Reconnected // console.log('UDC Reconnected');
fe980000.usb // console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
```

Now at first thought I thought it was a permission issue causing the `EBUSY` error but then I noticed that the order of the outputs was all out of whack. Additionally, I can write to the file just fine using `echo` (no sudo - and I run the `app.js` file using `sudo node...`) in shell.

Any ideas why everything might be running asynchronously if that is indeed what is happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node's fs writeFile and readFile are asynchronous functions. If you want synchronous functions, you should be using fs.writeFileSync and fs.readFileSync.

Note that this means you will have to remove the existing callback functions you have hanging off writeFile and readFile.

You can read up on the difference between the sync and non-sync functions in the Node.js docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: Thanks for your response, so what would I do in place of the removed callback functions?

Comment: @SterlingButters - the response would be returned from the given function. So, you could do something like `const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');`

Comment: @LMulvey Thanks - I think I got it now! Can I use a try-catch on that? I.e. print the error without terminating process?

Comment: @LMulvey Nvm, got it